# Adaptive period of an average

Tags: pine-script

I try to build variation of the Hull Movong Average, where the input (length) depends on the current value of TR (true range) or ATR.

This is my code which does't work:

```
//@version=3
study("AdaptivePeriodHullMA",overlay=true)
in=input(title="period",type=integer,defval=16)


er= floor((tr (in)*10000))
n=in*er
```

I would like that Hull (or other average) would be calculated on the input which depends on the actual value of ATR or TR.

Is it even possible?

All suggestions will be really appreciated.

Comment: It should be possible. Do you know how to calculate Hull Moving Average? Also, `n` is a built-in variable which corresponds to current bar number. Please don't name your variables after built-in variables.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I know how to calculate Hull. This is the whole code (I changed 'n' for 'r':                                                                 '//@version=3
study("AdaptivePeriodHullMA",overlay=true)
in=input(title="period",type=integer,defval=16)


er= floor((tr (in)*10000))
r=in*er
n2ma=2*wma(close,round(r/2))
nma=wma(close,r)
diff=n2ma-nma
sqn=round(sqrt(r))


n2ma1=2*wma(close[1],round(r/2))
nma1=wma(close[1],r)
diff1=n2ma1-nma1
sqn1=round(sqrt(r))


n1=wma(diff,sqn)
n2=wma(diff1,sqn)
c=n1>n2?green:red
ma=plot(n1,color=c)'

Comment: Please edit your question and add new information there.

Comment: It seems that variable er breaks whole code. My guess is that I am in a way violating Pine's casting system here. When I change r =in*r for r = in * 1, it works.